# Python: install investpy in pycharm on anaconda 3 (python 3.6) interpreter

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, anaconda

Based on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233546/python-call-pandas-datareader-with-isin-or-wkn-or-translate-this-into-ticker-sy/70235978#70235978) I want to install the package **investpy** into pycharm with interpreter anaconda (python 3.6). For some reason the installation itself is not possible and pycharm itself shows me the error:

```
error:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.


PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - investpy

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

with the recommended way through anaconda [website](https://anaconda.org/alvarob96/investpy) I installed it via pip command. But the package already exists:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/alvarob96/simple investpy
```

Installation message:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.anaconda.org/alvarob96/simple
Requirement already satisfied: investpy in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.25.1 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from investpy) (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=4.4.1 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from investpy) (4.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2019.3 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from investpy) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from investpy) (1.21.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Unidecode>=1.1.1 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from investpy) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.2.0 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from investpy) (52.0.0.post20210125)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.22.0 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from investpy) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas>=0.25.1->investpy) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->investpy) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->investpy) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->investpy) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->investpy) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./Downloads/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=0.25.1->investpy) (1.15.0)
```

In the anaconda interpreter it still isn't available:
[image]

Is there a way to install the package with pycharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this for me doing this:

```
pip uninstall investpy
```

Then install it using PyCharm:

[image]