# Python: Transform ISIN, WKN or RIC to Yahoo Ticker Symbol?

Tags: python, stock, pandas-datareader, ticker, isin

Based on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233546/python-call-pandas-datareader-with-isin-or-wkn-or-translate-this-into-ticker-sy/70235978#70235978), I have the possibility to transform the ISIN to some form ticker symbol with help of library **investpy**. This transformation is correct for most of united states stocks.

But this symbol itself is not in any case the same as the ticker-symbol I need to call pandas_dataframe. I think more exactly it conforms the RIC-symbol (e.g. look [here](https://www.patria.cz/akcie/HNKG_p.F/henkel-kgaa-preferred-stock/ospolecnosti.html?culture=en-US)).

For example if I try the following call:

```
import investpy

df = investpy.stocks.search_stocks(by='isin', value='DE0006048432')
print(df)
```

My output is:

```
       country        name  ... currency     symbol
0      germany  Henkel VZO  ...      EUR     HNKG_p
1        italy  Henkel VZO  ...      EUR     HNKG_p
2  switzerland  Henkel VZO  ...      EUR  HNKG_pEUR
```

but

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

stock = pdr.DataReader('HNKG_p', data_source="yahoo", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-10-30")
```

gives me an error.

The correct call I need is:

```
stock = pdr.DataReader('HEN3.DE', data_source="yahoo", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-10-30")
```

So my question is:

- is there a way to transform an ISIN, maybe WKN or also RIC to the
  ticker-symbol yahoo needs for DataReader call.

Or more general

- Is there a way to get historical stock data with the knowledge of ISIN, maybe WKN or RIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super ugly and error prone but better than nothing:

```
import investpy as ip
import yahooquery as yq
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

company_name = ip.stocks.search_stocks(by='isin', value='DE0006048432')
company_name = company_name["name"][0].split(' ')[0]
symbol = yq.search(company_name)["quotes"][0]["symbol"]
stock = pdr.DataReader(symbol, data_source="yahoo", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-10-30")
```

You could extend this code using things like fuzzywuzzy and an ordinary testing module with doctest. Do not use this code in production.

I am not even sure if this call keeps the order of the returned values:

```
yq.search(company_name)["quotes"]
```

So this code might actually behave randomly but it might give you a direction.